# Need a Way to Search through Event Logs by RecordID

Tags: c#, wpf, event-log

I am trying to search through a folder with Event Logs in them, eventpath has the path of the specific Event Log I want to access. I want to use a specified RecordID to find it's correlated FormatDescription and display it in a MessageBox. I want to be able to use the eventpath to access each Event Log since I am using 6 separate .evtx files and need to use this method on all of them.

I found this solution, but I get an error when I'm trying to Query. I've tried to find a fix, but it seems as if it's just not going to work for what I need. I commented where exactly it is occurring in the code.

This is the exception: System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException: The specified path is invalid.

***I can't find a fix for this code, but if anyone knows a fix or another way to approach searching through Event Logs by RecordID and giving the corresponding FormatDescription, it would be greatly appreciated.***

I am using C# in Windows Presentation Foundation.

```
public void getDesc(string recordid)
        {

            string eventpath = getEventPath();
       
            //takes off the .evtx of the path
            string result = eventpath.Substring(0, eventpath.Length - 5);
           //result1 is going to be similar to this:
           //C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\randomTempDirectory\additional_files\DiagnosticInfo\WindowsEventLogs\Application

            string sQuery = "*[System/EventRecordID=" + recordid + "]";
           
            var elQuery = new EventLogQuery(result, PathType.LogName, sQuery);
          
            //this is where it errors out
            //error: Specified Channel Path is invalid
            using (var elReader = new System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader(elQuery))
            {

                List<EventRecord> eventList = new List<EventRecord>();
                EventRecord eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent();
                try
                {
                    while ((eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent()) != null)
                    {
                        //Access event properties here:
         
                        string formatDescription = eventInstance.FormatDescription();
                        MessageBox.Show(formatDescription);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (eventInstance != null)

                        eventInstance.Dispose();

                }
            }
            

        }
```

Comment: Why tag this with WPF?

Comment: I am using WPF so I thought I should tag it. I'm new so I don't know what the correct etiquette is

Answer (score 0):

The path here is not the physical path on your machine it is the type of event log you are looking into "Application","Security" ...etc.